# Why does super closure not use the new base class given by a metaclass?

Tags: python, dynamic, subclass, super, metaclass

I'm toying with creating a class that dynamically has a base that is the class of an object passed to it on instantiation. E.g. pass it an `int` instance, and it subclasses `int`, etc. I'm trying to do this by employing a metaclass. This seems to break `super`. `__class__` ([a closure created if `super` exists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object)) and the no-arguement form of `super` do not acknowledge the new base class.

With `__class__` / `super()` broken, I'm not sure how to do what `super()` would have done. `super(self.__class__, self)` "works", but would break subclassing *this* class.

Why does `__class__` not match `self.__class__` in this case? I know they aren't equivalent concepts, but in here, I'd want them to have the same value. See the factory function alternative below. `print(isinstance(self, Class))` also returns false. My guess is that [because of the way `super` and `__class__` are created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36994027/913080) when the code is parsed, it is initially set without considering the change in the metaclass, and the adoption of a new class created with `type` doesn't change the `__class__` already set - though I'd have guessed it would. After all, you're supplying the new class, aren't you?

Can `__class__` / `super()` be "fixed"? If it can't, can `super` still be somehow used cleanly?

I tried creating a class to do what I wanted `super` to do, with `__getattribute__`, but that's also pretty dicey.

See this runnable example with illustrative prints:

```py
class Base:
    pass

class Meta(type):
    def __call__(mcls, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        bases = (obj.__class__,)

        __dict__ = dict(mcls.__dict__)
        if "__dict__" in __dict__:
            del __dict__['__dict__']
        if "__weakref__" in __dict__:
            del __dict__['__weakref__']

        cls = type(mcls.__name__, bases , __dict__)
        instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance

class Class(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(__class__.__bases__)
        print(self.__class__.__bases__)
        print(isinstance(self, Class))
        print(isinstance(Class, Meta))
        print(isinstance(self, __class__))
        print(isinstance(self, self.__class__))

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
In [1]: Class(Base())
(<class 'object'>,)
(<class '__main__.Base'>,)
False
True
False
True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-6a5013764b7e> in <module>
----> 1 c = Class(Base())

<ipython-input-54-f1865febd768> in __call__(mcls, obj, *args, **kwargs)
     19         instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     20         # Sets obj in instance for mutables
---> 21         instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     22         return instance
     23

<ipython-input-54-f1865febd768> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     30         print(isinstance(self, self.__class__))
     31
---> 32         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     33

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

---

#### Factory function

I'm aware that the above could be done simply with a factory function that looks like this:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Base init")

def get_instance(obj):
    class Class(type(obj)):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(__class__.__bases__)
            print(self.__class__.__bases__)
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return Class()
```

which yields

```
In [1]: get_instance(Base())
Base init
(<class '__main__.Base'>,)
(<class '__main__.Base'>,)
Base init
```

In this example, `super()` finds the `Base` class because that's what it was defined with, and intuitively finds the Base's init dunder method. Rephrasing my question:

If I instead use a metaclass to dynamically subclass something, how can I get `super()` to find the dynamic base, just as it would if I had used a factory function? If it cannot (cleanly), are there reasonable alternatives?

#### Another phrasing

Finally, another way I think this question can be restated is:

*How can normal subclassing be effectively emulated with a Metaclass?*

#### Why?

Firstly, this behavior surprised me, and I'd like to understand it. In that regard this can be viewed as an academic question.

Beyond that, the question of how to dynamically sublcass [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350082/change-class-parent-dynamically-from-attributes-python-3) [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438923/python-dynamic-subclassing), and there's clearly non-zero interest. But, the methods I've seen all seem lacking. `super` / `__class__` seems problematic for metaclasses, and if that and everything else worked wonderfully (big if), there's still a concern about metaclass conflicts one might have to worry about in the general case. Using factory functions might seem simple, but they make it difficult to subclass the class you're creating. It's not straight forward to subclass the `Class` above in the factory function example. Using a metaclass, if you could get it to work, would still allow plainer access and subclassing.

Comment: "I'm toying with creating a class that dynamically has a base that is the class of an object passed to it on instantiation." This is fundamentally not the right approach to this.

Comment: `__class__` in a method (specifically, a function defined within a class body) and `obj.__class__` **are two completely different things that are specifically meant not meant to match (although they may)**. `obj.__class__` is simply the class of that instance, i.e. `type(obj) is obj.__class__`, the special variable `__class__` is a specially defined variable that references the statically defined *class object* that *a class definition statement* is creating. Usually, you *don't want* `super(self.__class__, self)`

Comment: So consider a method `foo()` that exists in a base class, that isn't overwritten in subclass. i.e. `Sub` inherits `Base.foo`. So when you create `sub = Sub()` then call `sub.foo()`, if you had `print(__class__, self.__class__)` in `Base.foo`, you would see `sub.foo()` print out `Base Sub`

Comment: So in your code specifically, `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` will **always** be equivalent to `super(Class, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` *that's the whole point*.

Comment: But fundamentally, again, this is just working **against the whole machinery of class based inheritance** to do what should probably just be solved with a factory function and no dynamic inheritance.

Comment: Well, yes, that's another reason `super(self.__class__, self)` is a bad idea. I tried to head that off by providing another reason not to do that, because that's commonly cited. I thought bringing that up would help clarify my intent, but maybe not. To your other comments, I edited my post to try to clarify further.

Comment: Look, I don't know what to tell you. Again, you are working against the whole class machinery. The *reasonable option* is to stop trying to use a metaclass to do this and just use the factory function.  But "dynamic inheritance" is a huge red-flag -- inheritance is *not meant to be dynamic in this sense*.  You are using the wrong tool to do something that is probably the wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: Now, you could always  create *some hack*, like your metaclass could add an attribute `cls.__init__._special_attribute = cls` and then in the `__init__` you would just write `super(self.__init__.__func__._special_attribute, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: But again, this is all just jumping through hoops to break the way things are *supposed* to work for no obvious benefit. Note, in your proposed solutions, `instance = Class()` then `isinstance(instance, Class)` **would be false** and `isinstance(Class, Meta)` would also be false. So you are subverting the class machinery, to hackily try to reproduce it. You are creating your own problem and coming up with a "solution" that just implements what classes already do in a worse way, when you should just be using them the way they were meant to be used

Comment: And *basically* you want something like the prototype-based inheritance (for example, as seen in Javascript), but you are trying to use the *class based machinery* to achieve this. But you might as well just implement prototype-based inheritance from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your dynamic class does not inherit from itself (`Class`) at all - the implicit `__class__` variable inside your `__init__` points to the "hardcoded" "Class" version - but the `self` received when `__init__` is called is an instance of the dynamic class, which does not have `Class` as its superclass. Thus, the arguments filled implicitly to `super()`: `__class__` and `self` will mismatch (self is not an instance of the class defined in `__class__` or of a subclass of it).

The reliable way to fix this is to allow proper inheritance, and forget copying the class `__dict__` attributes around: let the inheritance machinery take care of calling the methods in the appropriate order.

By simply making the dynamic class inherit from your static  class and the dynamic-base, all methods are in place, and `self` will be a proper instance from the baked-in `__class__` from `__init__`.`__class__` still points to the static `Class`, but the conditions for super to be called are fulfilled - and super does the right thing, by looking for the supermethods starting from the `self` parameter - the newly created dynamic subclass which inherits both from your static `Class` and the new `Base`, and calls the methods on `Base` as they are part of the `__mro__` of the new class, in the correct place.

Ok - sounds complicated - but with some print statements added we can see the thing working:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("at base __init__")

class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        dynamic_ancestor = type(obj)
        bases = (cls, dynamic_ancestor,)

        new_cls = type(f"{cls.__name__}__{dynamic_ancestor.__name__}", bases , {})
        instance = new_cls.__new__(new_cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance

class Class(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(__class__.__bases__)
        print(self.__class__.__bases__)
        print(isinstance(self, Class))
        print(isinstance(Class, Meta))
        print(isinstance(self, __class__))
        print(isinstance(self, self.__class__))
        print(self.__class__.__mro__, __class__.__mro__)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Class(Base())
```

Outputs:

```
at base __init__
(<class 'object'>,)
(<class '__main__.Class'>, <class '__main__.Base'>)
True
True
True
True
(<class '__main__.Class__Base'>, <class '__main__.Class'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>) (<class '__main__.Class'>, <class 'object'>)
at base __init__
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot of sense that explicitly naming `Class` as a base would fix `super()`. I still have two questions though, because I don't understand the inner workings. 

1) In my original, I expected `self` to still be an instance of `Class` because that's ultimately the class we're assigning the instance too, in the metaclass. Why isn't it? I guess it just takes the result of the `type` call verbatim, but I didn't expect that, given we're in the context of the metaclass that's being used explicitly.

Comment: 2) Why does `__class__.__bases__` still not reflect `Base` - and also now `Class`? Though that seems to not matter practically. Thanks again!

Comment: 1) In your original code, `self` is an instance of your newly created `cls` class which only base is "obj.__class__` and there are no mentions in the hierarchy to `Class`

Comment: 2) `__class__`, unlike `self.__class__` is "baked in" when the class statement which body contains the method where `__class__` appears is resolved. It takes place after the call to the metaclass `__new__` method (and I don't recall is before or after the metaclass `__init__` is called.  I think after). Once "Class" is defined, the value for `__class__` inside `Class.__init__` is bound to `Class`itself and immutable - only creating `Class` a new, with a new reference to  `__init__` creating a new `__init__` closure for the original one, could change it.

Comment: What makes my example work is that the `__mro__` from a derived class is defined to include other superclasses in the super() call hierarchy - even when walking the hierarchy up from a superclass that would have no intermediates to `object`, like is the case: it is the way multiple inheritance works in Python.

Comment: About 1) Right, I think I get that that is the case now. I originally thought that since the metaclass isn't being used in a vacuum, the interpreter might use the context it can see, and make the instance an instance of `Class` without explicitly saying so. But maybe it's a deliberate choice to not do that for me. This way does seem to give more explicitly control since it's really using exactly the class produced by the `type` call, and not adding anything behind the scenes. So it seems more powerful this way, even though my intuition was wrong.

Comment: About 2) Makes sense. Then, if I really wanted to alter a `__class__` from the metaclass, it would have to be in the metaclass's `__new__` when creating an instance of `Class` - but it's `__call__` that can receive the object to get the dynamic base from, not `__new__`. So `__class__` seems stuck where we have it. That's fine though. :)